# Maven Sonar Scanner Exclude a directory

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to exclude a directory of generated source code files from being analyzed by the Maven Sonar Scanner plugin.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
├── processors
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── org
│                   └── protobuf
└── schemas
    └── src
        └── main
            └── java
                └── org
                    └── generated
                        └── models
                            └── ModelA.java
                            └── ModelB.java
```

I'm trying to exclude everything under schemas.

When I run the command I do the following:

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar
-Dsonar.projectKey=myProjectKey
-Dsonar.projectName=myProjectName
-Dsonar.login=myLoginKey
-Dsonar.password=myPassword
-Dsonar.language=java
-Dsonar.sources=.
-Dsonar.exclusions=schemas/**/*
-Dsonar.junit.reportPaths=target/surefire-reports
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco-ut.exec
```

The output says:

```
[INFO] Excluded sources:
[INFO]   schemas/**/*
...
[INFO] 2 files indexed
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

I'd like to exclude that entire directory, and all of it's contents.  How do I get sonar scanner to do this?

Comment: Just updated.. I had -Dsonar.source=src...  I had the property misspelled and I changed it to the current director.. -Dsonar.sourcess=.

Comment: Do you have one project or multi-modules project? Please add content of the `pom.xml` file.